# Delphi/Pascal string literals to C/C++

Tags: c, delphi, string

I am trying to write a function to transform a string literal in Delphi/pascal to the C equivalent. A string literal in Delphi matches the regex `("#"([0-9]{1,5}|"$"[0-9a-fA-F]{1,6})|"'"([^']|'')*"'")+` so that the string

```
"This is a test with a tab\ta breakline\nand apostrophe '"
```

will be written in Pascal as

```
'This is a test with a tab'#9'a breakline'#$A'and apostrophe '''
```

I managed to strip the apostrophes, but I am having trouble managing the special characters.

Comment: Did you try writing a parser?

Comment: What exactly are you after? A "C" routine that does it? A "Delphi routine that does it? A regular expression?

Comment: @ignacio it is actually part of a larger parser, and I very much would like not to have to write another for the strings.

@Cosmin I am looking for a C++ function that does it.

Comment: The [tag:delphi] tag here is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `replaceApp()` function that can be found at: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/basic_string/replace

Then code can look as:

```
string s1 = "This is a test with a tab\\ta breakline\\nand apostrophe '";
string s2 = s1;
s2 = replaceAll(s2, "'", "''");
s2 = replaceAll(s2, "\\t", "'$7'");
s2 = replaceAll(s2, "\\n", "'$10'");
cout << "'" << s2 << "'";
```

Of course changes '\t' -> '$7' can be saved in some structure that you can use in loop instead of replacing each item in separate lines.

Edit:

Second solution (example taken from comment) with using [`map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C%2B%2B%29):

```
typedef map <string, string> MapType;
string s3 = "'This is a test with a tab'#9'a breakline'#$A'and apostrophe '''";
string s5 = s3;
MapType replace_map;
replace_map["'#9'"] = "\\t";
replace_map["'#$A'"] = "\\n";
replace_map["''"] = "'";
MapType::const_iterator end = replace_map.end();
for (MapType::const_iterator it = replace_map.begin(); it != end; ++it)
    s5 = replaceAll(s5, it->first, it->second);
cout << "s5 = '" << s5 << "'" << endl;
```

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is the opposite, in C I have `"'This is a test with a tab'#9'a breakline'#$A'and apostrophe '''"` and I want to obtain `"This is a test with a tab\ta breakline\nand apostrophe '"`